# Why am I getting runtime error using snprintf?

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to convert an array of integers, A[] to array of strings,B[] and then I'm finally converting the array of strings to a single string. I'm getting runtime error. Kindly check.

```
for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
    {
        int a=A[i],digits=0;
        while(a!=0)
        {
            a=a/10;
            ++digits;
        }
        B[i]=(char*)malloc(digits+1);
        snprintf(B[i],digits+1,"%d", A[i]);
    }
    char *x=B[0];
    for(i=1;i<n1;i++)
        strcat(x,B[i]);
```

Finally x contains my string which I've created using strcat function by concatenating all B[i]'s

Why runtime error?

Comment: `strcat(x,B[i]);` is the same as `strcat(B[0],B[i]);` because `x` points to `B[0]`. You aren't supposed to copy all the strings to `B[0]` as `B[0]` is full. Instead of `char *x=B[0];`, allocate memory for `x` using `malloc` and then, `strcpy` first, then `strcat` all the rest of the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Because `B[0]` is initialized to some "small" size, the length of `A[0]` digits. `strcat` then writes to unallocated memory.

On way to solve this is to maintain a global length counter, allocate `x` to the right size, and `strcat` everything, including `B[0]` into in.

Comment: I tried using this:


char *x=(char*)malloc(totaldigits+1);
    for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        strcat(x,B[i]);
//Still the same error :(

Comment: either use `calloc`, or at least initialize `x[0] = 0;`.